# Is there a way to combine many gbr files (GIMP) into a set of brushes like an abr file?

Tags: gimp, brush

I was answered here recently that GIMP can use abr files but can't compile gbr files into abr.

1. Does GIMP have an alternative file type for a set of brushes?
2. How do I create one with the gbr files I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no equivalent format in GIMP. However you could put .gbr files inside a ZIP folder for upload/download purposes. This has nothing to do with GIMP though.

To create one in Windows, right click your desktop or any blank space inside a folder, choose New > Compressed (zip) folder. Open the zip folder, and copy and paste your .gbr files inside it. I've no idea how to do this on other operating systems, sorry. You could google it.

To use the .gbr files, they'd need to be extracted from the ZIP, then moved to GIMP's brush folder so that GIMP can read them.